# $(X,Y)$ gaussian and $X-\alpha Y$ independent with $X$

Tags: vectors, random-variables, gaussian

Suppose $U =\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}$ is a random gaussian vector.
The question is : find the conditions of existence of a real $\alpha$ such that $X-\alpha Y$ and $X$ are two independent random variables.

What I do:

We must have :

$$Cov(X-\alpha Y, X)=0$$
$$Cov(X,X) - \alpha \, Cov(Y,X)=0$$
$$\alpha = \frac{Var(X)}{Cov(X,Y)}$$
My conclusion: there exists an $\alpha$ if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Is it the good answer?

Comment: You've shown that if $X,Y$ are *not* independent then $X-\alpha Y,X$ are independent for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. This does not justify the reverse direction. It's also worth mentioning that your argument is relying on the fact that if $(X,Y)$ is a *Gaussian* random vector then $X,Y$ are independent iff $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=0$. This need not be true if $(X,Y)$ had some other joint distribution.